# how to display dicom image in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, dicom

I want to ask about this function in matlab `dicomread`

example :

```
a = dicomread ('m.dcm');
imshow(a)
```

---

the image showed in the screen but it is very dark.....I wonder way it is dark and not normal.
I checked with different dicom images but the problem remain.
I hope you can help me and 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are dealing with monochrome images, you can set a linear scaling between a minimum and maximum pixel value as follows:

```
img = dicomread('filename');
imshow(img, [minAllowedPixValue maxAllowedPixValue]);
```

Alternately, you can display the image at full dynamic range:

```
imshow(img, []);
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you need to read the image colormap together with the data, then pass it to IMSHOW:

```
[a, amap] = dicomread ('m.dcm');
imshow(a,amap)
```

Answer (score 0):

`dicomread` returns a multi-band image.

Try

```
a = dicomread ('m.dcm');
figure();imshow(a(:,:,:,1));
```

Comment: @user-x, can you post the image?

Answer (score 0):

Try

`im = dicomread('image.dcm');`

`im = im2double(im); % this line to convert from uint16 to double`

`im = mat2gray(im); % this line to put the data in range [0,1]`

`figure;imshow(im);`